# SELECT data from multiple tables using joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have follwing tables

USERS :

```
* id
* name
* role id
* phone
```

STUDENTS

```
1: userid ( fk users.id)
2: course_id
```

STAFF

```
1: staff_id(fk users.id)
2: course-id
```

COURSES

```
1: COURSE_ID
1:COURSENAME
```

I need to find all accounts associated with a number

I need name,userid,roleid,courseid,corsename,staffid, by providing mobile

i have written this query but this return zero results

```
SELECT users.name, users.id, staff.user_id, students.course_id, users.role_id, courses.course_title FROM users INNER JOIN students ON users.id = students.user_id INNER JOIN staff ON staff.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN courses ON courses.id = students.course_id WHERE users.phone = '9495990028'
```

LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Some of the fields are inconsistent. The fields that you mention each table and the fields that you mention at the end of this question have some little difference.

Comment: Please publish at least an attempted solution, demonstrating your effort so far to solve the problem.

Comment: i am only giving a mobile number.my need is to get details of user. a user may students or teacher. this must join to course table inorder to get course details of a users.this is my requirements

Comment: 'SELECT users.name, users.id, staff.user_id, students.course_id, users.role_id, courses.course_title
FROM users
INNER JOIN students ON users.id = students.user_id
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN courses ON courses.id = students.course_id

WHERE users.phone = '9495990028'
LIMIT 0 , 30'

Answer (score 2):

Try **union** operator:

```
SELECT name, s.userid, roleid, s.course_id, c.coursename, null
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN STUDENTS s 
INNER JOIN COURSES c
ON s.userid = u.id AND c.course_id = s.course_id
WHERE u.phone = ?
UNION 
SELECT name, null, roleid, s.course_id, c.coursename, s.staff_id
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN STAFF s
INNER JOIN COURSES c
ON s.staff_id = u.id AND c.course_id = s.course_id
WHERE u.phone = ?;
```

Comment: I have listed the columns as per the list mentioned by you. As per the rules of UNION clause both the queries should return same number of columns. However, if you want either userid from student table or staffid from staff table then null can be removed

Comment: ok..i had removed..but u didn't joins the courses table in the above code. i want to know that why did you use AND clause. the query works without AND clause.is this AND make any difference

Comment: Sorry .. my bad..forgot to put Course table ..but then how did the query work?Anyways, editing the query...

Comment: the what is the need of AND clause..'AND c.course_id = s.course_id' .. it works without AND clause too..pls share

Comment: You mean to say with ",", how did you try..can you please share the conditionals you tried

Comment: `SELECT u.name, s.user_id, role_id, s.course_id, c.course_title, r.display_name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN students s ON s.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.id = s.course_id
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.role_id
WHERE u.phone = '?'
UNION
SELECT u.name, s.user_id, role_id, s.course_id, c.course_title, r.display_name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN staff s ON s.staff_id = u.id
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.id = s.course_id
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.role_id
WHERE u.phone = '?'`    i didnt use **AND** clause and i get same results

Comment: That is just the other way of doing it..any one of them will work fine.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the COURSES table, I check the id with the course_id from students and staff

```
SELECT name, s.userid, roleid, s.course_id, c.coursename, st.staff_id
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN STUDENTS s ON s.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN STAFF st ON st.staff_id = u.id
INNER JOIN COURSES c ON c.course_id = s.course_id AND c.course_id = st.course_id
WHERE u.phone = ?
```

Comment: no i want to search for the students and staffs for the same mobile number. assume that a teacher is a parent and teaches the same class

Comment: huh, there is no mobile number field in any table. Please be clearer when asking the question.

Comment: ah, sorry, you mean the phone field in the USERS, right?

Comment: yes..it's ok. i will my efforts to solve this problem. will post my query so that you can understand what i intended to get